# How to fix memory issues in Vista

Tags: windows-vista, memory

When I open task manager, I have 13 chrome.exe and 11 svchost.exe killing me, the biggest usage of memory is mbamsvc though. What is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Chrome is functioning like it's designed.  Does starting up in a minimal startup help?

Comment: You should note how much RAM you have and how much is in use.

Comment: post some pictures of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229

Answer (score 2):

mbamsvc is the Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Real-Time module. You could fix it by uninstalling it and installing different anti-virus. There are also [reports](https://forums.malwarebytes.org/index.php?showtopic=141334) of excessive memory use with version 2.0 of Malwarebytes. They are aware of the problem and appear to be working on a fix.

Comment: Chris, you're alive! Good to see you again!